# Android Studio: onActivityResult not being executed after closing gallery

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to android development and trying to teach myself. Currently I am trying to add a functionality in my app where I click a button and the gallery opens up for a user to select an image to be used later and then a dialog box is supposed to show up after the gallery closes. However, after closing the gallery nothing happens and it seems  that the onActivityResult() code does not run for some reason. I get no error in logcat and Log.d statments do not show up. Code below. Thanks!

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        
        Log.d("TEST1", "FUN EXECUTED")


        val fab = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fababc)
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            showCreateTodoList()
            Log.d("TEST2", "RECIEVING INPUT")

        }
    }


   private fun showCreateTodoList() {
        openGallery()

    }

 private fun openGallery() {
        val gallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        requireActivity().startActivityForResult(gallery, p)
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)   {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == p){
            Log.d("TESTING", "THIS CODE RUNS")
            imageURI = data!!.data



            activity?.let {
                val dialogTitle = getString(R.string.newScp)
                val positiveButtonTitle = getString(R.string.create)
                val myDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
                val todoTitleEditText = EditText(it)
                todoTitleEditText.inputType =
                        InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS
                myDialog.setTitle(dialogTitle)
                myDialog.setView(todoTitleEditText)
                myDialog.setPositiveButton(positiveButtonTitle) { dialog, _ ->

                    uri = imageURI.toString()


                    val list = viewData(todoTitleEditText.text.toString(),uri,R.drawable.image,"SCP Name: ", "SCP Class", "Date Discovered: ", "Kill Count:" )
                    addToList(list)
                    dialog.dismiss()
                    ListItemCLickedu(list)

                }
                myDialog.create().show()
            }




        }
        else{  Log.d("TESTING2", "THIS CODE DOES NOT RUN!")


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code,i try this and works fine:

```
 private lateinit var imageURI: Uri

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_MEDIA = 101
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Log.d("TEST1", "FUN EXECUTED")

        button.setOnClickListener {
            showCreateTodoList()
            Log.d("TEST2", "RECIEVING INPUT")

        }
    }


    private fun showCreateTodoList() {
        openGallery()

    }

    private fun openGallery() {
        val gallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(gallery, REQUEST_MEDIA)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_MEDIA) {
            Log.d("TESTING", "THIS CODE RUNS")
            imageURI = data?.data!!

                // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setMessage("Dummy Dialog Title")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                            // what you want to do on positive click
                            dialog.dismiss()
                        })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                            dialog.dismiss()
                        })
                // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                builder.create().show()

        }

    }
```

Please check if you add permissions in your manifest file and also if you are in fragment check if activity in `activity?.let`  is null. If so, try something `getBaseActivity()?.let` or  `applicationContext?.let` and in there display your dialog.